# Angular.js - Change url from login page causes logged in area glitch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, authorization, single-page-application

I have a confusing situation somebody probably already had.

I am implementing login / authentication with angular.js.

I've done everything like described in this link

> https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec

Now I separated www.url.com/login.html and www.url.com/index.html#dashboard.

Dashboard is the logged in area.

If I am on the login page (www.url.com/login.html) and in url i enter www.url.com/index.html#dashboard the dashboard starts loading and then redirects me back to login.html.

The problem is that I see the dashboard page for a few seconds and then I get redirected after seeing the dashboard loading.

Using window.location in  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) ..

Is there any way to bypass / override this behaviour?

Comment: Please post your entire code. It could be a number of things and impossible to tell without looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

That article is not the show of brightests techniques. There are lots of $rootScope.$broadcast which are considered a code smell. Anyway, as I can see, he is using AnguarUI router. So, that component (same as generic router) has one feature you are looking for - [resolves](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha).

Idea is simple - that definition describe a variable that can be injected into Controller. But, if that variable is a promise, Controller will delay rendering of the view until that promise is resolved. So there will be no glitch.

[Egghead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr1qZ8Ik9G8) made a screencast from which you can get the idea how this feature works. But - integrating this feature into login process can be hard if you are not very talented and creative programmer. I didn't find any tutorial about that.